# IF NOT EXIST option is not coming in SQL server 2012 while generating script file

Tags: sql-server-2012

Not getting "IF Not EXIST" option is not getting in sql server while generating script file. This option was present in sql server 2008 but not showing in 2012

Answer (score 2):

While generating script file in SQL  Server 2012 we can’t see the “IF NOT EXIST’ option , which was present in SQL Server 2008 to check the existence of the object. This feature is also present in 2012 but we have make true the option “Check for object existence” to get the same output  as SQL Server 2008.

Comment: This is not an answer. you can edit your question to put this in.